# Error Loading PDF Files in React-PDF `Worker was destroyed`

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

I am trying to create a custom PDF viewer with react-pdf v6.2.0 to load in PDFs that I get from an API that are stored as base64 strings.

The following is the code I currently have:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Document, Page } from "react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack";

export function PDFViewer({ pdfFile }) {
  const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(null);
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);

  return (
    <>
      <Document
        file={`data:application/pdf;base64,${pdfFile}`}
        onLoadSuccess={({ numPages }) => {
          console.log(`PDF File drawingId: ${pdfFile.DrawingId}`);
          setNumPages(numPages);
          setPageNumber(1);
          alert("PDF document loaded successfully!");
        }}
        onLoadProgress={({ loaded, total }) =>
          alert("Loading a document: " + (loaded / total) * 100 + "%")
        }
        onLoadError={(error) =>
          alert("Error while loading document! " + error.message)
        }
        onSourceSuccess={() => alert("Document source retrieved!")}
        onSourceError={(error) =>
          alert("Error while retrieving document source! " + error.message)
        }
      >
        <Page pageNumber={pageNumber || 1} />
      </Document>
    </>
  );
}
```

When I run the code, I get "Document source retrieved!" twice, followed by "Error while loading document! Worker was destroyed", followed by "Loading a document: 100%", and finally "PDF document loaded successfully" even though nothing is shown or the a PDF page is shown.

Thee issue is that for some PDFs nothing is displayed and for all PDFs, regardless of if there is a page displayed, I get the "Worker was destroyed" error and the "Document source retrieved" message twice.

Do you have any ideas what the issue is and what can be done to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Question is quite old . But use memo for memoizing error .